# Use list of files saved in text file to search for string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 sets of operations, in the 1st one I look for files that contain a string, then in second one I use that list to extract lines that contains another string and then edit them.

```
$List_Of_Files = Get-ChildItem "$outputfolder*.html" -recurse | 
  Select-String -pattern "https://www.youtube.com" | group path | 
    select name -ExpandProperty Name

$List_Of_Titles = @(Get-Content $List_Of_Files | Where-Object { $_.Contains("<title>") }) | 
  Foreach-Object {
    $content = $_ -replace "    <title>", "  <video:title>";
    $content -replace "</title>", "</video:title>"
  }
```

Code works as expected, but the problem is that I need the 1st set of operations to output results into a text file and then use that file in second set which should also output results into another text file.

I have tried the following, but second set doesn't create the file, but doesn't give me any error either.

```
Get-ChildItem "$outputfolder*.html" -recurse | 
  Select-String -pattern "https://www.youtube.com" | group path | 
    select name -ExpandProperty Name | Set-Content "c:\List_Of_Files.txt"

@(Get-Content "c:\List_Of_Files.txt" | Where-Object { $_.Contains("<title>") }) |
 Foreach-Object {
    $content = $_ -replace "    <title>", "  <video:title>";
    $content -replace "</title>", "</video:title>"
 } | Set-Content "c:\list_of_titles.txt"
```

I have tried to modify it in different ways, but can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Does the file c:\List_Of_Files.txt get created?

Comment: Yes it does get created

Comment: I just tested it with a dummy file containing some <title> tags and your last pipeline worked. Could you show as a digest of the content of List_Of_Files.txt?

Comment: Side note: `Set-Content` produces *ASCII* files by default, causing any foreign chars. to be replaced with literal `?` chars.; if that's a problem, use the `-Encoding` parameter to change that.

Comment: List_Of_Files.txt just contain complete path to files for example:
c:\folder\another folder\some file name that contains a string.html 
etc. etc

Comment: And if you simply omit the `Set-Content` call (last pipeline segment), you do see output on the _screen_?

Comment: Just tried, nothing happens no error, no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c:\List_Of_Files.txt` contains a list of *file paths* and you're trying to filter that list by whether the *path* contains `"<title>"`, which results in no matches.
(I have no explanation for why your 1st snippet worked.)

Your problem stems from **confusion over what objects are being passed through the pipeline**: you start with *file paths* (strings), then threat them as if they were the files' *content*.

Instead, I assume you meant to test the *contents* of each file identified by its path.

A quick fix would be:

```
Get-Content "c:\List_Of_Files.txt" | Where-Object { Select-String -Quiet '<title>' $_ }
```

Note, however, that you must also adapt the `ForEach-Object` command accordingly:

```
Foreach-Object {
    # Read the content of the file whose path was given in $_,
    # and modify it.
    # (If you don't want to save the modifications, omit the `Set-Content` call.)
    $content = ((Get-Content $_) -replace "    <title>", "  <video:title>");       
    $content = $content -replace "</title>", "</video:title>";
    # Save modifications back to the input file (if desired).
    Set-Content -Value $content -Path $_;
    # $content is the entire document, so to output only the title line(s) 
    # we need to match again:
    $content -match '<video:title>'
    # Note: This relies on the title HTML element to be on a *single* line
    #       *of its own*, which may not be the case; 
    #       if it isn't, you must use proper HTML parsing to extract it.
 }
```

To put it all together:

```
Get-Content "c:\List_Of_Files.txt" | Where-Object { Select-String -Quiet '<title>' $_ } | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $content = ((Get-Content $_) -replace "    <title>", "  <video:title>");
        $content = $content -replace "</title>", "</video:title>";
        Set-Content -Value $content -Path $_;
        $content -match '<video:title>'
     } | Set-Content "c:\list_of_titles.txt"
```

Note that you can make the whole command more efficient by removing the filtering step that uses `Select-String` and performing the filtering inside the `ForEach-Object` block.

Also, the string replacement could be optimized or, preferably, handled with true HTML parsing.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know how to "finish" your code, in the last line of the `ForEach-Object` block i have put path to a text file like this - `$_  c:\list_of_titles.txt` but i get error saying - Unexpected token 'c:\list_of_titles.txt' in expression or statement. Could you let me know how to fix it please? Sorry for the confusion i obviously don't know much about powershell.

Comment: @PeterPavelka: It sounds like you were converting my code back to a one-liner and simply forgot a `;` before `$_` (in multiline code you don't need a `;` at the end of a line). The more important question, however: what are you trying to save to `"c:\list_of_titles.txt"`? Is it the _file paths_ or the _actual title strings_? If the latter, the code won't work.

Comment: No i didn't do anything else except adding `"c:\list_of_titles.txt"` at the end as you suggested, and i need to save the actual titles as i explained in the original question, 1st snippet gives me list of files that include a string `https://www.youtube.com` , then i use that list in 2nd snipped to extract lines with string `"</title>"` and then in all those lines i replace title tags by video title tags and save the results into a file, so yes i need the actual titles as output.

Comment: @PeterPavelka: Please see my update (just revised), and note the caveat re HTML parsing.